# Проблема с анимацией урона у персонажа,как её решить?

Tags: c#, unity3d, анимация

можете пожалуйста помочь реализовать анимацию урона при соприкосновении с врагом,вот мой скрипт CollisionDamage:

```
public class CollisionDamage : MonoBehaviour 
{
 public int damage =10;
 [SerializeField] private Animator animator;
 private Health health;
 [SerializeField] private SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;
 private float direction;
 public float Direction
 
 {
     get{ return direction; }
 }
 private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col) 
 {
        if (GameManager.Instance.collisionContainer.ContainsKey(col.gameObject)) 
        {
            health = GameManager.Instance.collisionContainer[col.gameObject];
            direction = (col.transform.position - transform.position).x;
            animator.SetFloat("Direction", Mathf.Abs(direction));
            
        }
}
 public void SetDamage()
 {
     if (health!=null)
     health.TakeHit(damage);
     health =null;
     direction = 0;
     animator.SetFloat("Direction",0F);
 }
 
    
}
```

Как мне в этот скрипте прописать анимацию урона для персонажа,задумка такая:соприкосновение есть,урон идёт,нет соприкосновения нет и урона.
P.S этот скрипт прикреплён к врагу.
Cама проигровка анимации происходит в игроке в данном месте(скрипт Player):

```
animator.SetBool("isGrounded",groundDetection.isGrounded);
    if(!isJumping && !groundDetection.isGrounded)
    {
      animator.SetTrigger("StartFall");
      animator.SetBool("Damaged",false);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Не уверен, но может быть так?

```
public void SetDamage()
{
    if (health!=null) {
        health.TakeHit(damage);
        health =null;
        direction = 0;
        animator.SetFloat("Direction",0F);
    }
}
```

Comment: Это же одно и то же)Эти строчки,которые вы написали у меня верно написаны.Мне нужно чтобы в момент анимации укуса проигрывалась анимация урона у игрока.

Comment: Далеко не одно и то же. Обартите внимание на оператор ветвления и фигурные скобки. @Юрий

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский,извините невнимательно посмотрел.